# Both TreeMap and TreeSet create a new empty incarnation TreeMap.empty, TreeSet.empty. Is this fixable?

Tags: scala

As a best practice there should be no more than one instance of a collection type floating around. For example, Nil is a case object in the scala library.

However, both TreeMap and TreeSet create a new instance upon each empty() call. After playing around with this for a while, it's clear that the problem is the fact that orderings are not covariant. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the only problem. Another problem is that both `TreeMap[A]` and `TreeSet[A]` need an implicit `Ordering[A]` parameter for insertion and removal of values.

As you can see in the sources of [`scala.collection.immutable.Set`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala) you could otherwise simply cast a `Set[Any]` to `Set[A]` if it is empty as the type parameters are erased at runtime anyway.

Comment: Yes, but is the following possible? An Ordering[Nothing] is trivially defined, and we can possibly let the first element inserted bring its ordering with it.